# picture cut offs in Wordpress/ not being fit

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

[image]

As you can see in the picture, when I upload my product images to WordPress the head of models cut off and I cannot see the full image in thumbnails. Does anyone have any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Did you regenerated your thumbnails?

Comment: no. what do you mean? can you explain please ?

Comment: There are free plugins available to regenerate thumbnails after changing the thumb size. Install one of them and then regenerate all thumbnails. Check after reloading. #Make sure to take backup first

Answer (score 0):

you can set thumnails without crop , just add custom thumnail in function.php and use it , like this :

in function.php ::

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'my-thumb', 50 ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, resize mode (whitout croped)
}
```